# Xamarin AndroidClientHandler sending client certificate

Tags: android, ssl, xamarin, httpclient, client-certificates

I think I may be missing something here, but how do you send client certificates to a SSL site that requires a client certificate.

I am using HttpClient and passing an AndroidClientHandler

There are lots of answers that provide code but do not tell me why the code works or when it should be called. I've spent over a week on this.

Can someone just provide a simple code example and a simple explanation of why it should be done like this.

I am using self signed certificates. I have managed to ignore any certificate validation, and can call the SSL site when it is configured not to require a client certificate.

But now I need to know how to pass the client certificate.

I've looked at many articles and solutions but I don't see where the client certificate is passed.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps try what is in this blog: https://dotnetdevaddict.co.za/2015/07/31/self-signed-certificates-and-xamarin-android/comment-page-1/ . Generally the recommendation is not to use self-signed certs since official certs issued by a CA are cheap or free. Self-signed certs complicate things.

Comment: Looking at this it mentions a self signed certificate. Are they talking about the SSL certificate on the web application, or are they talking about a client certificate? Again it is not clear in the article why I need to do this, I want to understand the principles not just copy code into my application.  Unfortunately for the moment all I have is self signed certificates so I am stuck in the situation.

Comment: I'm coming to the conclusion that you cannot use Xamarin HttpClient and AndroidClientHandler to send client certificates in an HTTPS request. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: I can confirm that if you use AndroidClientHandler that the System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback will never be called. If you need to set and use that callback, you have to use the managed HttpClient handler.

Comment: Hi @jgoldberger not quite sure what you mean. How does this relate to using Xamarin HttpClient and AndroidClientHandler to send client certificates in an HTTPS request

Answer (score 1):

The Xamarin examples I've seen leave out adding the IPrivateKey to the KeyStore that's used to populate the KeyManagerFactory

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a Java X509Certificate with private key
/// </summary>
public class CertificateDetails
{
    public CertificateDetails(IPrivateKey privateKey, X509Certificate[] chain)
    {
        PrivateKey = privateKey;
        Chain = chain;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the private key
    /// </summary>
    public IPrivateKey PrivateKey { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets certificate chain
    /// </summary>
    public IReadOnlyCollection<X509Certificate> Chain { get; }
}


/// <summary>
/// HttpClientHandler based on native Android  <see cref="Java.Net.HttpURLConnection"/> that uses a client certificate
/// </summary>
public class AuthAndroidClientHander : AndroidClientHandler
{
    readonly CertificateDetails _certificateDetails;

    public AuthAndroidClientHander(CertificateDetails certificateDetails)
    {
        if (certificateDetails is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(certificateDetails));
        }
        _certificateDetails = certificateDetails;

        //get root certs
        var trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.GetInstance(TrustManagerFactory.DefaultAlgorithm);
        trustManagerFactory.Init((KeyStore)null);
        var x509trustManager = trustManagerFactory.GetTrustManagers().OfType<IX509TrustManager>().First();
        var acceptedIssuers = x509trustManager.GetAcceptedIssuers();

        //trust both default issuers and chain of client certifiate
        TrustedCerts = _certificateDetails.Chain.Concat(acceptedIssuers).ToList<Certificate>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configure keyStore passed into <see cref="AndroidClientHandler.ConfigureKeyManagerFactory"/> and <see cref="AndroidClientHandler.ConfigureTrustManagerFactory"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="keyStore"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override KeyStore ConfigureKeyStore(KeyStore keyStore)
    {
        // replace keyStore generated by base class with a PKCS12 instead of the default KeyStore.DefaultType
        keyStore = KeyStore.GetInstance("PKCS12");

        //replicate base's SetupSSL() behavior of adding all TrustedCerts to keystore in  
        keyStore.Load(null, null);

        if (TrustedCerts?.Any() == true)
        {

            for (var i = 0; i < TrustedCerts.Count; i++)
            {

                Certificate cert = TrustedCerts[i];
                if (cert == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                keyStore.SetCertificateEntry($"ca{i}", cert);

            }

        }

        //add private key to keystore
        keyStore.SetKeyEntry("privateKey", _certificateDetails.PrivateKey, null, _certificateDetails.Chain.ToArray());

        return keyStore;
    }

    protected override KeyManagerFactory ConfigureKeyManagerFactory(KeyStore keyStore)
    {
        var kmf = KeyManagerFactory.GetInstance("x509");
        kmf.Init(keyStore, null);
        return kmf;
    }

    protected override TrustManagerFactory ConfigureTrustManagerFactory(KeyStore keyStore)
    {
        var tmf = TrustManagerFactory.GetInstance(TrustManagerFactory.DefaultAlgorithm);
        tmf.Init(keyStore);
        return tmf;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great for me. I was able to add a client certificate from the user credentials keystore as well.